# Photographing an object that's moving past a stationary camera

Tags: camera

I want to automatically snap high-resolution photos of objects moving past a camera (or a video camera). Due to limited computational power, I need to keep as few frames as possible. I need the entire object to be within frame.

To make it a bit more concrete, lets start with an analogous problem; There's a camera by the end of a gun barrel, and I need the camera to be able to snap a picture of the bullet when it passes by. The entire bullet needs to be within frame. We don't know when the gun will fire nor do we know the exact velocity of the bullet.

Currently, I have played with some motion detectors like:

1. Lasers.. Once motion is detected, the photo is taken after n microseconds
2. Higher framerate but lower res video cameras that can be used to determine if a frame of the higher resolution video camera is to be kept

The first solution is suboptimal since I cannot be sure what n should be. The second requires additional hardware.

I cannot shake off the feeling that a more elegant solution must exist.

Answer (score 1):

The way this is typically solved is by having a rolling window of high-speed video data, and only the last n seconds are stored when some trigger event (such as your laser) occurs. But the concepts of "I want speed-of-sound image processing" and "I have computational resource restrictions" are at odds with each other here.

Comment: Unless the former leads to the latter....